# Use dbt to load JSON files into staging

Tags: dbt

Is it possible to use dbt to copy data from files into the database?

I've got some files as data sources and I would like to load them into an staging layer before starting to process them.

Something such as this command in postgresql:

```
COPY staging.test (json_content) from 'C:\tmp\46002.json'
```

But as far as I see in the documentation, the models require a SELECT statement and the COPY statement fails when running `dbt run`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From raw local files? No.

Your two dbt direct data options are:

1. Load some size limited datasets via dbt [seeds](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/building-a-dbt-project/seeds) which only supports csv's currently.
2. load data from cloud hosted storage like s3 buckets via [external-tables](https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-external-tables).

This is the best resource to explain why this application doesn't attempt to support the EL part of the ELT (Extract-Load-Transformation) process:

[What is dbt - dbtLabs Blog](https://blog.getdbt.com/what-exactly-is-dbt/)

Without getting into tool recommendation, you'll need an additional component to your data stack to handle the extraction process for you. dbt presumes the data has been loaded into a "pre-processing" or "raw" area of your warehouse generally following Lewis Gavin's excellent architecture here:

[How to architect the perfect Data Warehouse - Lewis Gavin](https://lewisdgavin.medium.com/how-to-architect-the-perfect-data-warehouse-b3af2e01342e)

---

Edit: Additional notes on the seed data - currently comma separated is the only format supported. Some discussion in [this issue](https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-core/issues/3990) about extending that to other delimiters and escape formats.

No current support for seeding json files. Also [under discussion](https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-core/issues/2365).